# SIPSorcery .NET WebRTC what is the alternative to ontrack?

Tags: webrtc, sipsorcery, ontrack

I posted the question here but nobody replied: https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/sipsorcery/issues/983

I know that in standard JS WebRTC there is an event named ["ontrack"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/track_event).

However, SIPSorcery doesn't support this event. It's still [in their todo list](https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/sipsorcery/blob/2e28a633ff675915d3e593cab338580f01a76122/src/net/WebRTC/IRTCPeerConnection.cs#L411-L420).

My goal is to grab the remote track and get audio stream from it. If ontrack is not supported by SIPSorcery yet, what is the alternative? Thanks.